# firebug, inspect element etc. Is there a way to hide it?

Tags: html, firebug, inspect-element

I'm just wondering for example I have a code like this:

```
<input type="text" value="value" id="txtbox" style="display:none" />
```

is there a way that it could not be crawled or find at firebug? or any other inspect element?

hope my question make sense
thanks in advance for response :)
..

Comment: No; all the code you send to the browser is visible to the browser. Why are you trying to hide elements from the user's view?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: ah ok. thanks for that mr David Thomas and Stanley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Anything within an HTML document, as served by a server, can easily be processed simply by doing a GET request on it and reading the result as plain text. So anything you might try in HTML, CSS, JavaScript or FooScript would have no effect.