# How to Block inspect element on browser

Tags: inspect-element

Can I block inspect element on browser ?
I want to block inspect element on my webpage, when a user try to modify code in inspect element, he could not do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firebug, inspect element etc. Is there a way to hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698446/firebug-inspect-element-etc-is-there-a-way-to-hide-it)

Comment: Maybe the new HTML5 DRM standard will make this possible somehow. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

No, it is not possible. Your server is sending a response on a request, the browser is just an interperter of the code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) it receives. This means that this code will have to be sent to your computer. When it leaves your server you have no influence on it anymore.